# Prove $\lim_{t \to 0} \int_R |f(x+t) - f(x)| dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real-value Lebesgue integrable function on $R$. Prove that 
\begin{equation} 
\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{R} |f(x+t) - f(x) | dx =0 
\end{equation}

---

I have seen the proof of this using approximation theorem. Using the fact that continuous compact functions are dense in $L^1$. Now, I wonder if I can use the Dominate Convergence Theorem to prove this as well.

Since $f(x + t) - f(x)| \leq 2|f(x)|$ which is in $L^1(R)$ we then have 
\begin{equation} 
\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{R} |f(x+t) - f(x) | dx =  \int_{R} \lim_{t \to 0}|f(x+t) - f(x) | dx = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: $|f(x+t)-f(x)|\leq 2|f(x)|$ is not true in general. For example, take $f(x)\chi_{[0,1]}$. Then for $x<0$ and take $t=1-x$, we have $|f(x+t)-f(x)|=f(1)-f(x)=1$, but $2|f(x)|=0$.

Comment: ahh I see... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (*after seeing the comments*: "A") problem with your approach is that, for a fixed $x\in\Bbb R$, $\lim_{t\to0} \lvert f(x+t)-f(x)\rvert=0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x$. So it's not true that you'll end up integrating the constant zero function, if you start with a general $L^1$ function. So, AFAIK, you do need to start with $C_c(\Bbb R)$ and proceed by approximation.

Comment: I didn't think about that (stupid me). Thank you for your insight.